# SVM visualization really random and inaccurate

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, svc

```
def vec(utterance): 
    embedder = UtteranceEmbedder(utterance)
    word2vec = embedder.as_word2vec()
    bow = embedder.as_bow_vec()
    ret = np.concatenate([word2vec, bow])
    return np.pad(ret, [0, 500-len(ret)], "constant")

op = OptionParser()
op.add_option(
    "-f", "--file", help="path to file containing utterances to visualize",
    action="store", type="string", dest="path"
)

(opt, args) = op.parse_args()
if opt.path is None or (opt.path is not None and len(opt.path)) == 0:
    op.error("path to file containing newline separated utterances must be specified")

vectors = []
with open(opt.path) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    # you may also want to remove whitespace characters like `\n` at the end of each line
    for utterance in [x.strip() for x in content]:
        vectors.append(vec(utterance))


vectors_reduced = TSNE(n_components=2).fit_transform(np.array(vectors))
X=np.array(vectors_reduced)
y=np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1])
clf = svm.SVC(decision_function_shape='ovo',class_weight="balanced)
clf.fit(X, y)
```

An utterance will be a phrase, I will tokenize the utterance, extract word2vec vector form Google 300B trained model, append with a bag of words vector and fit the data.
Following is my training data:
Input.txt

```
yea
yeah
yaa
say
ok
okay
no
nope
not interested
dont
cant
cannot
not now
not really
not at the moment
no thank you
sorry no
sorry
not active
```

As you can see its a simple case of opposites, When I plot the points using matplotlib, I get as random as possible not linearly seprable.[image: Triangles depicts yes and other is nos]

What could be the case for such a completely inaccurate occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a svc with the standard parameters. Especialy your Kernel is an rbf kernel (also known as gaußian). How SVM's work a litle bit too complicated to post here and with a kernel it's even more complex. If you are intrested i can recommend you the lecture from MIT.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_PwhiWxHK8o

But in short your gaußian kernel does the separation still linear but in a higer dimensional vectorspace. It transforms your data for the separation into that space and separates it linearily with a hyperplane. If you visualize your data later with your support vectors in two dimensions the separation is not linar but in your "kernel-vector-space" it is.

Btw. you should also think about [standardization](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65094/why-scaling-is-important-for-the-linear-svm-classification).